# how to using express routing in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, express, routes

I'd like to use express routing with angularjs.

My web service was consisted as below.

My server routing has two ways.

```
1. http://localhost/login // has 2 sub client routings (/#login, /#register)

2. http://localhost/main  // has some client routings (/#profile, /#content, etc)
```

I want to go to **http://localhost/main/#profile** from **http://localhost/login/#login**.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK neither `$location`, nor `ngRoute` which is based upon it, are made to access this fragment of URL. You'll have to use legacy JS, using `window.location.replace(URL)`.